# Make linux spin up all disks at once

Tags: linux, hard-drive, raid

I have a server running an 8-disk software RAID. On boot, all disks are spun up simultaneously, which takes about 5 seconds.

To save energy, I make them spin down after 15 minutes of inactivity. When they are re-activated later, the kernel spins them up one after another, taking almost a minute in total.

Is there any way to change that behaviour?

Comment: FWIW: You'll lose more money in broken disks due to wear and tear from spindown than you'll save in energy

Comment: I'd say that depends on the frequency of spin-ups. I'm currently at about 5/day.